# how do I save the CSV and not download

Tags: php, mysql, csv, wget

I have this php script

```
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
mysql_select_db(DATABASE, $connection);
$query = sprintf( 'SELECT * FROM something' );
$result = mysql_query($query);
header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=export.csv' );
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
if ( $row )
{
  echocsv( array_keys( $row ) );
}
while ( $row )
{
  echocsv( $row );
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
}
function echocsv( $fields )
{
  $separator = '';
  foreach ( $fields as $field )
  {
    if ( preg_match( '/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $field ) )
    {
      $field = '"' . str_replace( '"', '""', $field ) . '"';
    }
    echo $separator . $field;
    $separator = ',';
  }
  echo "\r\n";
}
```

which grabs all the records and saves them into a csv ....which works great. But what i need to do is run this php script from a cron and save the csv a specific folder...any ideas

here is how i am calling the file via a cron task

```
wget -O /dev/null http://somesite.com/make_csv.php
```

Comment: fputcsv() http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: Where are trying to save this? On the server or on the wget host? Perhaps you should look at what -O on wget does.

Comment: on the server is where i want to save it

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the fopen and fwrite functions, should do the job.

Comment: @ceejayoz - how do i use file_put_contents in this situation, would it be after the two header statements

Comment: You wouldn't want the header statements, nor the echo statements. You'd want to generate the CSV as a string and save that string to a file using `file_put_contents`.